# Ariston boiler with 108 error code

Tags: gas, boiler

I have an Aniston gas boiler. It's displaying error code 108. After Googling I found it's because of the low water pressure. Other forums indicate I should open the water valves underneath until the pressure indicator says 1 or 1.5, however I have opened them all, in different combinations, and nothing works.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valve that worked was the round blue one underneath (and not the black ones). At first it was hard to turn, but it finally opened and the pressure went back up. Once it got to 1.5 I fully closed it and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

The set up on my boiler is different. You turn two small black valves (they are smaller than the rest) that are underneath. You turn them till the pressure reaches 1.5 bar and this sorts the problem.